# viewDidload method call issue

Tags: ios5

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
isInFullScreenMode = FALSE;

messageArrayCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {

    MessageModel* messageModel1 = [[MessageModel alloc] init];
    messageModel1.messageID= i;
    messageModel1.userName = @"Kimberly A. Mann";
    messageModel1.userImage =  @"MWMStaff.png";
    messageModel1.createdAt = @"06/07/2011 at 01:00 AM";
    messageModel1.content = @"After raising her two children, Kim joined the Monument Wealth Management team in 2009, managing the book keeping and other office tasks.In her free time, Kim enjoys spending time with her family, attending festive events and parades, and catching up on her favorite shows – Dancing with the Stars and Smash, to name a few";


    [messageArrayCollection addObject:messageModel1];
    //[messageModel1 release];
}

[self buildPages:messageArrayCollection];

flipper = [[AFKPageFlipper alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
flipper.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
flipper.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:flipper];
}


-(void)showViewInFullScreen:(UIViewExtention*)viewToShow withModel:(MessageModel*)model{
   NSLog(@" in show view inFullscreen");
  if (!isInFullScreenMode) {
    isInFullScreenMode = TRUE;

    CGRect bounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        CGFloat width = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = width;
    }


    fullScreenBGView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height)];
    fullScreenBGView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [fullScreenBGView setBackgroundColor:RGBACOLOR(0,0,0,0.6)];
    fullScreenBGView.alpha = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:fullScreenBGView];

    viewToShowInFullScreen =  viewToShow;
    viewToShowInFullScreen.originalRect = viewToShowInFullScreen.frame;
    viewToShowInFullScreen.isFullScreen = TRUE;
    FullScreenView* fullView = [[FullScreenView alloc] initWithModel:model];
    fullView.frame = viewToShowInFullScreen.frame;
    fullView.viewToOverLap = viewToShowInFullScreen;
    fullView.fullScreenBG = fullScreenBGView;
    fullScreenView = fullView;

    [self.view addSubview:fullView];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:fullScreenBGView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:fullView];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"SHOWFULLSCREEN" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.40];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:nil cache:NO];
    fullScreenBGView.alpha = 1;
    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        [fullView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 768-20, 1004-60)];
    }else {
        [fullView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 1024-20, 746-60)];
    }
    [fullScreenView rotate:self.interfaceOrientation animation:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView   setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationEnd:finished:context:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}


 }
```

Reaching `showViewInFullScreen` method by tapping particular area of screen to show full screen view,but when reaching to `[self.view addSubview:flipper];` then it is going back to `viewDidload` method , so not able to run the whole code in this method.And according to the behaviour it shouldn't go to this method.Why I am not able to add `subview` on it.searched a lot about `[self.view addsubView]` behaviour.It should add `subview` to the current window.Really not getting whats happening.if anyone can suggest what's wrong here will be thankful..

Comment: What class is this code in?

Comment: WallViewController.m class.whatever issue i have mentioned above is resolved its not going back to viewdidload method.Not able to add new view over the existing view through animation.nNot getting the point why not able to add another animated view over the screen